# js and css files are not read in a DJANGO project

Tags: python, django, media

I am reformulating a previous question because I think  it was formulated as a Python problem but it is a `Django` one.

I am installing a project from github called [publicmarkup](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/publicmarkup):

The main page displays on the browser but no media (neither js files, nor css files) are read loaded. There is a module called mediasync that seems to be necessary to display correctly the css and the js files of the templates.

I think this a configuration problem. Here's  the link [settings.py](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/publicmarkup/blob/master/settings.py) file, Here it could be find the root path of the media folder.

And here's the doc for the [mediasync](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-mediasync#an-important-note-about-django-13) modulet explains how to configure static_url

But I didn't understand anything since I am a newbie to djnago

Answer (score 0):

In Django you have to set up your own workstation serve static files, in both *dev* and *live* modes.

You can read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) explains how to serve static files in your *dev* environment.

In live mode you serve your static files directly via your end web server, usually either Apache or Nginx.

Comment: Thank you, I a m going to read it carefully and I'll let you know

Comment: I tried to follow the doc and added in my installed app the django.contrib.staticfiles module and I added the STATIC_URL and the STATIC_ROOT in settings.py, I added urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns(), and I have no change, my css and js still don't load